# Recommended way to change the size of the Toolbar in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

The toolbar in Codename one looks gigantic on my Android phone and on several other devices I tried (it looks great in the simulator). How can I change its size (`setSize` method should be avoided, it is for layout managers), for example by percentage of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codename1.demos.kitchen showing such an issue? Screenshots would be helpful. I'm assuming it doesn't happen in the kitchen sink but happens in your app which I'm guessing is because you changed the padding/margin of `Container`.

We have a hard assumption in Codename One that `Container` is transparent, has 0 padding/margin and has no styles.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the reason, I had made changes to the container's margin and padding

Answer (score 0):

Setting the padding and margin not to be derived, but to all zeros solved the problem. Hope it is useful for someone.